# Facebook Login using Javascript SDK does not give extended access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, facebook-access-token

So, [Facebook's documentation regarding access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending) says:

> Apps using the Facebook SDKs for Javascript, Android and iOS, desktop apps or apps using the server-side login flow automatically generate long-lived user access tokens.

But I'm using the Facebook Javascript SDK, and I'm using the regular old `FB.login`, but the access tokens I get back all have one hour expiration times.

Does anyone know what the deal is with this?  Is it a bug on Facebook's side?  Is the documentation wrong?  Is there a magic way to call `FB.login` that causes it grant you an extended access token?